# keyboard shortcut for toggling sessions of terminals in pycharm

Tags: python, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

I am recently started to use pycharm. Its embedded terminal is really cool. We can create multiple sessions of terminal using 'ctr+shift+t'. Also we can close sessions using 'ctrl+sht+w'. But how to toggle between these sessions? Is there any keyboard shortcut? Also where should I get list of all shortcuts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcuts:

- Next Tab = 'Alt'+'Right'
- Previous Tab = 'Alt' + 'Left'

While the cursor is in the Terminal.

You can see all the shortcuts in the menu (and add more, or change, or delete):

File -> Setting... -> [IDE Settings] Keymap